# viewPagerIndicator :Error:Artifact 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1:library.aar' not found

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

when I sync the gradle I have this error:

Error:Artifact 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1:library.aar' not found.

**my gradle is :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
}
```

what do I have to do?!

Answer (score 24):

Remove:

```
maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
```

and instead of

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

add:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

Clean and sync gradle.

Comment: you know why? @ziem pls explain something.

Comment: @HuyTower - I do not remember exactly but there were some problems with http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven. mcxiaoke created ViewPagerIndicator fork and pushed it to maven repository using `com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator` package name.

Comment: yes, I agree, I used mcxiaoke url. So it worked now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```